# String stretching mathematics in string theory

Tags: forces, string-theory, string

In, [Lecture 1 | String Theory and M-Theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25haxRuZQUk) by L. Susskind he says that some strings can be stretched to without the string snapping because they have a constant tension. If im not mistaken he was talking about non-relativistic strings. How would one show this mathematically?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which minute?

Answer (score 2):

An example would be an Abrikosov vortex line that joins two magnetic poles immersed in a superconductor. The vortex line has a constant energy per unit length (i.e a fixed tension) and you can move the poles as far apart as you like without it breaking because it must end on a magnetic pole.